# Can I change the word ubuntu from my plymouth default theme?

Tags: 10.10, plymouth

I have seen that plymouth themes in different distros are the same they just put a logo or a word..so if I want to put whatever I want...can somebody tell me with what program or editing what file?

Answer (score 11):

If you are happy with the rest of the theme, you can just replace the logo. In a terminal do the following:

1. backup the old logo

   ```
   sudo cp /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu_logo.{png,back}
   ```
2. put a copy of the logo on your desktop

   ```
   cp /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu_logo.png ~/Desktop
   ```
3. now edit the logo the way you want

   ```
   gimp ~/Desktop/ubuntu_logo.png
   ```
4. copy back your logo

   ```
   sudo mv ~/Desktop/ubuntu_logo.png /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/
   ```
5. update the system to use your logo

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
   ```

To restore the old logo, simply do:

1. restore old logo

   ```
   sudo cp /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu_logo.{back,png}
   ```
2. update the system to use the old logo

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
   ```

---

To test the theme without rebooting, you can run the following within a GNOME session to see a multi-window setup running your theme:

```
sudo plymouthd ; sudo plymouth --show-splash ; sleep 10 ; sudo plymouth --quit
```

Comment: Note that in 16.04, the themes directory location changed to: `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`

Answer (score 1):

*You cannot put whatever you want*, but you can choose from different themes.
That is because **Plymouth themes are basically animated images**, to customize them **is not as easy as editing a text file or an image with The Gimp**.
You can try to create your own theme using these guides:

http://brej.org/blog/?p=158
http://brej.org/blog/?p=174

Otherwise you can choice from existing themes:

- plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo
- plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text
- plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
- plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
- mythbuntu-default-settings
- plymouth-theme-fade-in
- plymouth-theme-glow
- plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo
- plymouth-theme-sabily
- plymouth-theme-script
- plymouth-theme-solar
- plymouth-theme-spinfinity
- plymouth-theme-text
- plymouth-theme-ubuntustudio
- plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo
- xubuntu-plymouth-theme

Just install one of these package, then from the terminal type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

You will be prompted to choose your theme, so choose it :)

Then, last command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you made a mistake in this line:

```
sudo plymouthd ; sudo plymouth --show-splash ; sleep 10 ; sudo plymouth --quit
```

I think that unless you it:

```
sudo plymouthd ; sudo plymouth --show-splash & sleep 10 ; sudo plymouth --quit
```

it will never leave plymouth.