# How can I change the purple background color of Ubuntu plymouth boot screen?

Tags: boot, plymouth, colors

I'd like to change the background color of the purple plymouth boot splash to another color, how can I do this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16845/can-i-change-the-word-ubuntu-from-my-plymouth-default-theme answers most of this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's pretty easy.

Open the file `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script` with an editor
and change the following 2 lines that can be found to something like this

```
Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.0, 0.00, 0.0);     # Nice colour on top of the screen fading to
Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.0, 0.00, 0.0);  # an equally nice colour on the bottom
```

save the file and run the following command.

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

The background of the boot splash should now be black instead of purple.

Note that in Ubuntu 16.04, the themes directory location changed to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`.

Comment: http://www.colorhexa.com/4dbcff was helpful for me to find the colour I wanted. Example: rgb(0, 159, 255), in percentage rgb(0%,62.4%,100%) means 0.0, 0.62, 1.0 for the ubuntu-logo.script.

Comment: Note that in 16.04, the themes directory location changed to: `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`

Comment: on Ubuntu-Mate 20.04 it's specifically `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-mate-logo/ubuntu-mate-logo.script`

Answer (score 10):

The path location has changed since Ubuntu 16.04. See below

To open the file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script
```

Then as before, edit these two rows:

```
Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.0, 0.00, 0.0);     # Nice colour on top of the screen fading to
Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.0, 0.00, 0.0);  # an equally nice colour on the bottom
```

And run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use a GUI then go with [Plymouth Manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/plymouthmanager/). It should be pretty straightforward and it lets you make a custom theme or pick one of the ones offered.