# How to change grub2 color?

Tags: boot, grub2

I want to change the grub2 menu color to black and white, also if it's related I wanted to change the purple color that appear between transitions when the PC boot.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: 2 seperate questions. Could you ask the other in a new question please?

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/q/20829/186134

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the background color, you could make an *image* the background.

Choose a  PNG image, copy it, open terminal, run the command `sudo nautilus /boot/grub`, input password and Nautilus (Ubuntu explorer) will be opened. Paste your image in the folder you were redirected to.

Open a new Terminal window, run `sudo update-grub`, wait for the process to end and reboot your computer. The chosen image should be your GRUB background then.

About the letters' color, it will be the perfect opposite of the background color.

So, if you want a black background, you could use [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Flag_of_Afghanistan_%281880%E2%80%931901%29.svg/2000px-Flag_of_Afghanistan_%281880%E2%80%931901%29.svg.png) image.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the site here.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-1404/

But if you want the command for the program suggested in website, it is here:

The program is called Grub Customizer and I have used it before and recommend it. Or moving to another boot loader is good too, which I can help you on too.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Good Luck and ask for help if needed.