# Changing Ubuntu 18.10 purple cryptsetup pass-phrase screen

Tags: boot, login, encryption

In reference to Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish). Using [change login screen purple background 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089843/change-login-screen-purple-background-18-10) answer I was able to change screen color for login screen, but the first screen that appears, the cryptsetup pass phrase screen, remained the same purple. I find this color shockingly disturbing, and would very much like to replace it with black or text mode screen.

:While editing appropriate lines in `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script` to;
`Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.0, 0.00, 0.0);     # Nice colour on top of the screen fading to`
`Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.0, 0.00, 0.0);  # an equally nice colour on the bottom`
does change the pass phrase screen eventually, the purple color still loads for about 3 seconds, then it turns black; like something else is loading color first. It also pops up for a second before desktop background loads.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20829/how-can-i-change-the-purple-background-color-of-ubuntu-plymouth-boot-screen

Comment: this script is located in `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script`

Comment: Thanks for that. This worked half way though purple color still loads for a few seconds then changes to black.

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/a/1127217/739431 https://askubuntu.com/q/1127236/739431