# 19.10: Change loading screen background color

Tags: themes

Is there a way to change the loading screen background of Ubuntu 19.10 to black from the default purple?

I have changed the login screen background by editing the CSS, which I saw in some other post here, and the grub boot loader background color. But after login it shows a screen with progress bar which is still purple. Is there a way to change the color to black?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing/hiding all boot screens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127189/removing-hiding-all-boot-screens)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the purple background color of Ubuntu plymouth boot screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20829/how-can-i-change-the-purple-background-color-of-ubuntu-plymouth-boot-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are talking about the Plymouth screen that appears before the login screen appears.

This has already been answered here.
[How can I change the purple background color of Ubuntu plymouth boot screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20829/how-can-i-change-the-purple-background-color-of-ubuntu-plymouth-boot-screen)

Inside of this file `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script`

Change these values.

```
Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.0, 0.00, 0.0);
Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.0, 0.00, 0.0);
```

Then run.

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: I have tired this. This worked for me when I logout, the splash screen with progress bar shows with black background