# How can I change the default boot text (Ubuntu 14.04) to custom text?

Tags: boot

I am wondering how to change the text that displays "Ubuntu 14.04 . . . ." on boot to a custom text.

Edit: I am talking about the ASCII text during the boot process, not the Ubuntu logo.

[image]

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/questions/16845/can-i-change-the-word-ubuntu-from-my-plymouth-default-theme

Comment: What "ASCII text during the boot process"? Are you talking of the GRUB menu, which Thiago's answer refers to, or something else altogether? Post a pic, if you can.

Comment: I need a reputation of 10 to post a pic. Let me see if I can link one. http://www.2daygeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-lts-desktop-installation-steps-with-screenshot-1.png

Comment: yeah, that is also a Plymouth theme - the text theme instead of the graphical one. The linked posts still apply.

Comment: Okay, but the links talk about backing-up and replacing .png files. Obviously this isn't a .png file.

Comment: Obviously instructions have to be adapted.

Answer (score -1):

I don't recommend it, but if you really need to customize the OS entry in the GRUB menu you just need to open (with `sudo`) the file `/etc/default/grub` and look for the line

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
```

You should replace

```
`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
```

with the custom string you want.

Don't forget to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

after changing the file.